# Is this testing a mean or a proportion?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

In $200$ families each with $4$ children, we observed the number of boys they had. Summary: $8$ families had $0$ boys, $42$ families had $1$ boys, $67$ had $2$, $70$ had $3$ and $13$ had $4$.

Can we say that families have boys $50$ percent of the time? Test this at $\alpha = 0.05$.

At first glance it seemed as if it were testing a proportion (the proportion of boys), but now it seems to me that this situation is addressing the mean of the number of boys, and we should test whether the mean number of boys in these families is $2$ or not. Am I right in my final reasoning? Currently, while posting this, I'm getting a feeling that we should test two means against each other, the mean number of boys and the mean number of girls, then compare the latter two to each other, so that the hypotheses look like: $H_0$: $\mu_1 = \mu_2$, $H_1: \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$, where each $\mu_i$ refers to a gender's mean. In short, I'm very confused at the moment. Can someone clarify things a little bit?

Comment: I think it's safe to imagine that, at least for purposes of this calculation, the only possibilities are "Boy" or "Girl" so knowing the statistics for one determines the statistics for the other.  To your earlier question, my reading of the problem would be "Using this data can we reject the null hypothesis of "random birth is equally likely to be a Boy or a Girl" using a confidence level of 95%?" .  At a crude glance (doing no calculation) I am surprised by the skew.  The data looks like $Prob(Boy)>.5$.  But it needs checking.

Comment: Hint:  that "70 had 3" seems way too high to me (under the assumption that $Prob(Boy)=.5$.  I'd focus on that one.  200 is a good sample size...use a normal approximation to calculate the mean and st.dev. for #families with 3 boys and see what the probability of seeing at least $70$ would be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do a goodness-of-fit test (i.e. a $\chi^2$ test) to determine if the number of boys follows $Bin(4, 0.5)$ based on your observed data.